# Dynamic class data in nuxt typescript app

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i tried to make some app.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <h1>user's page</h1>
    {{ user.id }}
    {{ user.data.getName() }}
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { User } from '~/typescript/classes/base/user';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Index',
  data() {
    const user: object = {};
    return {
      user
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.user = new User(1); // create user instance by ID
    this.user.loadAllServerData(); // call method to get server Data
  }
});
</script>
```

```
// this file works fine
export class User {
  private readonly id: number;
  data: Data;

  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  loadAllServerData(): void {
    this.loadUserInfo().then((info) => {
      this.data = new Data(info); // now 'data' has method 'getName()'
    });
  }

  getId(): number {
    return this.id;
  }
}
```

First, in mounted, I initialize the class, and then call the method that loads all the rest of the user information via user's id. Then this instance of the class should have a field 'data' with some other methods and fields like 'name'.

Its work, but when i try use it in my template, its not working reactive and i cant see changes in my class after 'loadAllServerData' and cant see user's name. How can i print user's name in my template?

I tried make it by AsyncData or fetch but without success

Comment: Hmm reactivity issues... Read these articles and you'll understand it  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html And  https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan i got `Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined
` in my console, so i dont think that it will help me

Comment: That's because data hasn't been fully loaded yet its being loaded asynchronously. So you need to do a null check in template

Comment: <span v-if="user.data">{{ user.data.name }}</span>

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan i think that is not right solve. Because i will must do it for every time

Comment: What you mean every time? The data is once loaded in your template by vue and then the template is re rendered again and again via vue's lifecycle hooks when your data changes. Plus your `loadAllServerData()` is asynchronous and your `user.data` is null in the beginning

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Moreover, even if I do this, the error disappears, but the class instance is not updated and I do not see the result of the function

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan every time when i will need to use similar data

Comment: Read about vue reactivity. The change detection is not triggered for object keys just by simple assignment. You will have to use this.$set() or something

Comment: Check those 2 links on my first comment and read them carefully

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan how can i use this.$set in Classes?

Comment: Vue.set(this, 'data', new Data(info)) not work too